# 3D pizza slicing

Tags: geometry, puzzle, 3d

I came across the following question:

> In front of you is a large pizza. The pizza may only be cut in straight lines. What is the maximum amount of pieces that the pizza can be cut into using $10$ straight cuts?

They are expecting the answer $56$. This follows from the series where the maximum number of parts is equal to the number of parts with one slice less, plus the number of slices you are allowed to make.

```
number of cuts   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
number of parts  1  2  4  7  11 16 22 29 37 46 56
```

This can be turned into $c\times(c+1)/2+1$ where $c$ is the number of cuts.

However, because the question is about pizzas and not about circles, you would be able to make pizza parts in $3$ dimensions. When trying to find a series by hand I got stuck at three cuts (which I believe can yield $8$ pieces).

Is there a series or a closed formula that describes the maximum number of parts when slicing a pizza in $3$ dimensions?

Comment: So instead of a circle, you assume the pizza is a cylinder?

Comment: The 3d version is known as [cake number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_number)

Comment: It is very difficult to slice a pizza in the third dimension, and the result is not very appetizing either

Comment: @FTem Yes. But I'm not sure if the cube (as poposed by @achille) yields the same number of parts as a cylinder.

Comment: Same set of numbers work for cylinder ( In fact, for any convex body ). Imagine you fix the planes that cut a cube into maximum number of parts. If you dilate the cube to infinitely large. You obtain a partition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into same number of parts. Since each part is the intersection of finitely many half-spaces, it will be convex. If you intersect such a part with any convex body. The intersection will be convex and hence connected. i.e. Each part of the partition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ give you at most one part of your convex body.